# How to create EF Core generic repository "on the fly" to use in MVC controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, generics, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

Creating a generic repository for EF core is easy. Let's asume we have the following base class:

```
 public class BaseRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        protected readonly MyContext Ctx = new ();
        public IEnumerable<T> Entities()
        {
            return Ctx.Set<T>();
        }
    }
```

What I usually do is to create a derived repository for a specific DbSet, like

```
public virtual DbSet<MyDatabaseTable> Table { get; set; }
```

and

```
public class TableRepository : BaseRepository<myDatabaseTable> { }
```

and than use this in my controller like this

```
public JsonResult Read_MyDatabaseTable([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
   return Json(new TableRepository().Entities().ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

What I WANT to do ist to have not repositiories for each table, instead to create the gernic type "on the fly" from a parameter like

```
public JsonResult Read_MyDatabaseTable([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string myTableType)
{
   return Json(new BaseRepository<myTableType>().Entities().ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: A side note: I hope this is just an example and you don't create concrete repository in your controller but rather you create/inject it on a interface. As for your question, create a repository factory or even the Unit of Work with a generic method of creating repositories. Doesn't have to be anything fancy, a plain switch-case would even do.

Comment: It is never a good idea to create a generic repository since it is mostly useless if you only don't create a student project https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/

Comment: @Serge: just a side note: not having repositories/how is great in a student project. In real cases, when some queries are manually optimized, run through dapper or even go beyond the database, an abstraction over EF is the only way to go. I often discuss this with juniors who bring such "you don't need repositories" articles into account. I guess such articles often lack the depth and just scratch the surface with the "you were wrong your whole life by unnecessarily complicating things".

Comment: My own 20+ years  net experience tells me that the generic repositories are mostly useless since the real queries you neeed usually much more complicated and  needs more joins then in generic repository.

Comment: My own 20+ years net experience tells me you are right as long as you only consider generic repositories. While you are clear on that in your comments, the linked article blurs the image. Consider my comment relevant to the article rather than your comments.